# Trying to generate a sitemap but getting this error?

Tags: wordpress, sitemap, yoast

XML Parsing Error: junk after document element
Location: http://jesteracademy.co.uk/sitemap_index.xml
Line Number 2, Column 1:
**Deprecated**:  Non-static method RP_Geositemap::add_to_wpseo_sitemap() should not be called statically in **/home1/jester/jesteracademy.co.uk/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php** on line **288**
^

Can anyone shed any light on what the above error means?

Wordpress site using the Yoast SEO plugin.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using any custom code, or just yoast?

Comment: Just Yoast. From the plugin.